# how to parse Laravel route file?

Tags: php, regex, laravel

In **roures.php** file has contain

```
    Route::get('roles/create',['as'=>'roles.create','uses'=>'RoleController@create','middleware' => ['permission:role-create']]);
    Route::post('roles/create',['as'=>'roles.store','uses'=>'RoleController@store','middleware' => ['permission:role-create']]);
    Route::get('roles/{id}',['as'=>'roles.show','uses'=>'RoleController@show']);
    Route::get('roles/{id}/edit',['as'=>'roles.edit','uses'=>'RoleController@edit','middleware' => ['permission:role-edit']]);
    Route::patch('roles/{id}',['as'=>'roles.update','uses'=>'RoleController@update','middleware' => ['permission:role-edit']]);
    Route::delete('roles/{id}',['as'=>'roles.destroy','uses'=>'RoleController@destroy','middleware' => ['permission:role-delete']]);

    Route::get('itemCRUD2',['as'=>'itemCRUD2.index','uses'=>'ItemCRUD2Controller@index','middleware' => ['permission:item-list|item-create|item-edit|item-delete']]);
    Route::get('itemCRUD2/create',['as'=>'itemCRUD2.create','uses'=>'ItemCRUD2Controller@create','middleware' => ['permission:item-create']]);
    Route::post('itemCRUD2/create',['as'=>'itemCRUD2.store','uses'=>'ItemCRUD2Controller@store','middleware' => ['permission:item-create']]);
    Route::get('itemCRUD2/{id}',['as'=>'itemCRUD2.show','uses'=>'ItemCRUD2Controller@show']);
    Route::get('itemCRUD2/{id}/edit',['as'=>'itemCRUD2.edit','uses'=>'ItemCRUD2Controller@edit','middleware' => ['permission:item-edit']]);
    Route::patch('itemCRUD2/{id}',['as'=>'itemCRUD2.update','uses'=>'ItemCRUD2Controller@update','middleware' => ['permission:item-edit']]);
    Route::delete('itemCRUD2/{id}',['as'=>'itemCRUD2.destroy','uses'=>'ItemCRUD2Controller@destroy','middleware' => ['permission:item-delete']]);
```

**Expected output:**

```
[
  [
  `url` => 'roles/create',
  'as' => 'roles.create',
  'uses'=>'RoleController@create'
  ],
[
  `url` => 'roles/create',
   'as' => 'roles.store',
   'uses'=>'RoleController@store'
  ],
]
```

as so on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you can get the file content using `file_get_content`, we are using regex for parsing file content using regex.

**Regex:** `/get\s*\(\s*'\K[^']+|as'\s*=>\s*'\K[^']+|uses'\s*=>\s*'\K[^']+/`

> `get\s*\(\s*'\K[^']+` Here this will match **Example:** `get('` match till `'`
>
> `as'\s*=>\s*'\K[^']+` Here this will match **Example:** `as'=>'` match till `'`
>
> `uses'\s*=>\s*'\K[^']+` Here this will match **Example:** `uses'=>'` match till `'`

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/781149)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$string="Route::get('roles/create',['as'=>'roles.create','uses'=>'RoleController@create','middleware' => ['permission:role-create']]);
    Route::post('roles/create',['as'=>'roles.store','uses'=>'RoleController@store','middleware' => ['permission:role-create']]);
    Route::get('roles/{id}',['as'=>'roles.show','uses'=>'RoleController@show']);
    Route::get('roles/{id}/edit',['as'=>'roles.edit','uses'=>'RoleController@edit','middleware' => ['permission:role-edit']]);
    Route::patch('roles/{id}',['as'=>'roles.update','uses'=>'RoleController@update','middleware' => ['permission:role-edit']]);
    Route::delete('roles/{id}',['as'=>'roles.destroy','uses'=>'RoleController@destroy','middleware' => ['permission:role-delete']]);

    Route::get('itemCRUD2',['as'=>'itemCRUD2.index','uses'=>'ItemCRUD2Controller@index','middleware' => ['permission:item-list|item-create|item-edit|item-delete']]);
    Route::get('itemCRUD2/create',['as'=>'itemCRUD2.create','uses'=>'ItemCRUD2Controller@create','middleware' => ['permission:item-create']]);
    Route::post('itemCRUD2/create',['as'=>'itemCRUD2.store','uses'=>'ItemCRUD2Controller@store','middleware' => ['permission:item-create']]);
    Route::get('itemCRUD2/{id}',['as'=>'itemCRUD2.show','uses'=>'ItemCRUD2Controller@show']);
    Route::get('itemCRUD2/{id}/edit',['as'=>'itemCRUD2.edit','uses'=>'ItemCRUD2Controller@edit','middleware' => ['permission:item-edit']]);
    Route::patch('itemCRUD2/{id}',['as'=>'itemCRUD2.update','uses'=>'ItemCRUD2Controller@update','middleware' => ['permission:item-edit']]);
    Route::delete('itemCRUD2/{id}',['as'=>'itemCRUD2.destroy','uses'=>'ItemCRUD2Controller@destroy','middleware' => ['permission:item-delete']]);";


preg_match_all("/get\s*\(\s*'\K[^']+|as'\s*=>\s*'\K[^']+|uses'\s*=>\s*'\K[^']+/", $string,$matches);
$result=array();
for($x=0;$x<count($matches[0]);$x+=3)
{
    $result[]=array(
        'url'=>$matches[0][$x],
        'as'=>$matches[0][$x+1],
        'uses'=>$matches[0][$x+2]
    );
}
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the following regex match and replace:

Match: `.*\('([a-z\/{}0-9]+)',\['as'=>(['a-z\.0-9]+),'uses'=>(['a-zA-Z@]+).*`

Replace: `[`url`=> $1, 'as' => $2, 'uses' => $3]`

PS. wherever you come by a space to match, use `\s`* to counter it